# Karma in angular doesn't import pixelmatch

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I use pixelmatch to test canvas elements. While importing pixelmatch in a component file works fine, karma won't import it in a spec file.

To reproduce the error:

```
ng new someproject
cd someproject
npm install pixelmatch @types/pixelmatch
```

Change

```
export = Pixelmatch
```

to

```
export default Pixelmatch
```

in 'node_modules/@types/pixelmatch/index.d.ts'

Since I'm still new to typescript I can't explain why it is needed but without it importing Pixelmatch is not working at all. Perhaps this is causing problems to karma.

I also install karma-firefox-launcher and change karma.conf.js to run tests in firefox.

Now

```
import Pixelmatch from 'pixelmatch'
```

in app.component.ts works fine,
but the same import in app.component.spec.ts doesn't .

```
expect(Pixelmatch).not.toBe(undefined)
```

is not passing.

I'd be grateful for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`import Pixelmatch = require('pixelmatch')`

For my NodeJS aplication with CommonJS syntax, it works like a charm!